# Line through the point of intersection of 2 lines

Tags: linear-algebra

> The equation of any line through the point of intersection of 2 lines $a_1x+b_1y+c_1=0$ and $a_2x+b_2y+c_2=0$ is $\big(a_1x+b_1y+c_1\big)+k\big(a_2x+b_2y+c_2\big)=0$

Well I can see the above statement if I consider some examples. But, what does it really mean ?, It'd b helpful to get some kinda of intuition into this ?

Comment: Did you forget to remove the $=$-signs inside the parentheses?

Comment: No, it isn’t. There is no value of $k$ that produces an equation of the second line. If you want to be able to express _any_ of the lines through the intersection point, you need to use the affine combination $(1-k)(a_1x+b_1y+c_1)+k(a_2x+b_2+c_2)=0$ or an arbitrary nontrivial linear combination of the two equations instead.

Comment: This is the dual of a statement about all of the points that satisfy the equation $ax+by+cz=0$.